# android textview Mouse Pointer

Tags: android

how to place mouse pointer on the textview in android

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_textView_fromText_studentLeaveApply"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:hint="From Date"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"/>
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do it. Why do you need this?

Comment: Do you mean cursor? Android doesn't have mouse pointer, and you shuold use EditText instead of TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse Pointer? If you are looking for focus, then `requestFocus` will help.

You can do it in either of the two ways:

**Way 1:**

```
             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_textView_fromText_studentLeaveApply"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:hint="From Date"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15sp">
                      <requestFocus/>
               </TextView>
```

**Way 2:**
in your Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       TextView view = findViewById(R.id.id_textView_fromText_studentLeaveApply);
       if(view!=null) view.requestFocus();
    }
```